# Does anisole react with concentrated nitric or sulfuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, reactivity

Can we add concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ and concentrated $\ce{HNO3}$ to anisole?

I heard that we can't add acids into phenol and aniline which make them blast.

Answer (score 4):

Anisole (methoxybenzene) is an electron-rich arene that will react with sulfuric acid or nitric acid in an **electrophilic aromatic substitution**.

*I suggest that you look the reaction up. Then grab a pencil, some sheets of paper and start to draw. Draw the arenium ions (Wheland intermediates) for the addition of the electrophiles at the different positions of anisole, have a look at the possible resonance structures and enjoy chemistry*.

---

**UPDATE**

<strike>Btw, you can do the same reaction with aniline or phenol without causing an explosion</strike>.

My comment on aniline and phenol only works on paper but not in real life and **Mithoron**'s comment on aniline and phenol is correct!

Nitroanilines and nitrophenols are synthesized in a different way.
In principle, nitration of aniline is possible with a mixture of nitric and nitrous acid, or after protecting the aniline as its formanilide.

Technically, 4-nitroaniline is produced by reacting 4-chloronitrobenzene with aqueous ammonia at elevated temperatures in an autoclave.

Details can be found in *Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry*:

> In the alternative continuous process, molten 4-chloronitrobenzene and 40 % ammonia liquor in a molar ratio of 1 : 17 are pumped at 20 MPa through a steel reaction coil held at 237-240 °C by oil bath heating. Inflow is controlled
>   to give a contact time of ca. 10 min, and outflow is directed into an expansion chamber with a tangential flow of hot water to give, in quantitative yield, a suspension of product that is readily isolated and washed.

The same is true for the formation of 4-nitrophenol. Again, the starting material is 4-chloronitrobenzene, which is reacted with strong aqueous $\ce{NaOH}$ to yield the phenol.

These two reactions are examples for **nucleophilic aromatic substitutions**!

Comment: aniline or phenol won't explode with conc. H2SO4 and conc. HNO3 but nitration won't occure but oxidation

Comment: Aniline can definitely be nitrated under these sorts of conditions. With phenol you might be better off using milder conditions e.g. just dilute nitric acid.

Comment: @J.LS I thought so too, but according to the Ullmann, the direct nitrations don't seem to play a role nowadays. That is, at least on a technical scale.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what reactions/synthetic approaches have replaced them in industry !

Comment: @J.LS I've added a procedure from *Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry* to my answer.